# Django: how do you get clean data from query by removing Decimal( in front of every value?

Tags: python, django

I want to have a clean list but when I run my query it returns "Decimal(" notation before every digit.
This is my query

```
processes = ProcessInfo.objects.filter(user_rel=user_pk).order_by('-id')      
process_score = processes.filter(user_rel=user_pk).values_list('process_score', flat=True)
      process_list = list(process_score)
      print(process_list)
```

What i get is:

```
> [Decimal('3797.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('301.00'),
> Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('144.00'), Decimal('55.00'),
> Decimal('181.00'), Decimal('0.00')]
```

Model:

```
process_score = models.DecimalField(default='0', decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True, editable=False)
```

How i am using it in js file :

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
           labels: {{ process_list|safe }},
           datasets: [{
               label: 'Automation Potential',
               data: {{ process_list_score|safe }},
```

How can I get rid of Decimal( ? I am using this data in a js chart. I would like to retun only values like this '3797.00, '0.00','301.00'....

Comment: Can you share the `ProcessInfo` model? `ProcessInfo.process_score` is a `models.DecimalField` right?

Comment: How are you using this in your JS? There may be better ways to include it

Comment: Plz do share suggestions I am always looking for a better way to do things but I would like to make this work

Comment: Can you share where you are using process_list in your JS?

Comment: You jump from Python code to JavaScript/ECMAScript code, without showing how you transfer the data. Assuming some JSON encoding in between, and that you want floating point numbers in JavaScript, convert the Decimal numbers to floats, e.g. `float(Decimal('12.34'))`. You can do this in a list comprehension for your list, or use `map`.

Comment: Please state what you mean with a "clean list".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) template tag to pass data from your view to some JS in a JSON format

```
{{ process_list|json_script:"process-list" }}
<script>
    const process_list = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('process-list').textContent);
</script>
```

The JS variable `process_list` will now be an array of strings without "Decimal"

You can then use this variable in your chart

```
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
       labels: process_list,
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed my model field type from DecimalField to FloatFieldand it worked, thank you all

```
process_score = models.FloatField(default='0', null=True, editable=False)
```